# Continuous function and it's supremum

Tags: real-analysis

> Let's assume that the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous in $\mathbb R$ and $f(0) = 1$. Also, $|f(x)| \leq \frac{5}{|x|}$ for all $x \neq 0$. Show that there exists $c \in \mathbb R$ such that $g(c) =\sup \{g(x): x \in \mathbb R\}$

So, is that supposed to be like that, or is it a typo, where do I get the function $g$ from?

Also, if that's supposed to be $f(c)=\sup\{f(x) : x \in \mathbb R\}$, how do I get it's supremum?

I assume $f(0)$ is one alternative (as in $\sup f(x)=\max(f(0),\text{ something})$)

Comment: Yes, it is a typo: evidently it is supposed to be $f$, not $g$.

Comment: You dont need to find it value, just show that this supremum is a maximum of the function. You can try a proof by contradiction.

Comment: You have to show that $f$ has a maximum. Do you know any theorem or result dealing with existence of maximums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $|f(x)| \leq \frac{5}{|x|}$ for $x \ne 0$ we see that $f(x) \to 0$ for $x \to \pm \infty$. Hence there is $a>0$ such that $f(x) \le 1$ for $|x|>a$.

$[-a,,a]$ is compact, thus there is $c \in [-a,a]$ with $f(x) \le f(c)$ for all $x \in [-a,a]$.

From $1=f(0) \le f(c)$, we see

$f(x) \le f(c)$ for all $x$

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Show that

1)  $f(x)$ has a maximum value $M\geq f(0)=1$ in $[-6,6]$ that is there is $c\in [-6,6]$ such that $M=f(c)=\sup\{f(x):x\in [-6,6]\}$.

2)  $f(x)\leq |f(x)|\leq \frac{5}{|x|}\leq \frac{5}{6}<1\leq M$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus [-6,6]$.

3) $M=f(c)=\sup\{f(x):x\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

P.S. Yes, I guess $g=f$ in your statement.